# Highcharts xAxis need same labels for three charts

Tags: highcharts

I have three HighCharts line graphs next to each other using Bootstrap. I would like them all to show the same xAxis labels. The first one shows 2025 and 2050. The second two show 2020 and 2040.  The first chart has a yAxis but the other two don't. I'm guessing because the first one is slightly narrower due to the yAxis, it shows different labels on the xAxis.  I would like all three to be the same.  I've tried using allowOverlap, rotation, and step but I can't get it to work.  Here's the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfjeld/0ubdk49n/12/).

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
    

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="container2"></div>
    </div>
                  
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="container3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="container4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container" id="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div id="container2"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div id="container3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div id="container4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.chart('container2', {
      title: {
        text: 'Low Battery Cost Case',
        style: {
          fontSize: '16px'
        }
      },

      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Capacity (GW)'
        },
        max: 300
      },
      labels: {
        step: 0
      },
      legend: {

        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        margin: 30,
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          pointStart: 2010,
          pointInterval: 2
        }
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Energy Time-Shifting & Operating Reserves (No Firm Capacity From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 4.21110359791565, 6.84334322867839, 7.20182619975514, 7.8004278261306, 10.1063979510877, 13.7963553953421, 14.6735914371287, 18.5837874315195, 20.3731482407672, 24.0988019699228, 32.0357544751444, 45.1519218212058, 56.3857942558924, 81.1292491322195, 95.7124408905994, 131.978838410468, ]
      }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Energy Time-Shifting (No Operating Reserves From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 3.70492103862706, 6.32644821179908, 6.7912945899555, 10.8852803548114, 17.2185962209215, 31.6655455463024, 53.0346762234928, 79.5213653476683, 99.0449876736713, 122.329600848415, 149.816960931063, 184.311271042092, 218.757764806966, 254.683442071981, 290.19930101708, 346.882919482988, ]
      }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Operating Reserves (No Energy Time-Shifting From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.5286257976622, 5.12758943424106, 5.99409380798642, 9.76453882541978, 12.0745968401012, 21.1834214272343, 33.1674795094693, 48.7307134642147, 56.9008609975166, 68.4659981520015, 84.0579790344369, 101.373936044519, 120.070540082055, 142.483062401683, 160.447936224237, 185.693139471677, ]
      }]

    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.chart('container3', {

      title: {
        text: 'Reference Cost Case',
        style: {
          fontSize: "16px"
        }
      },

      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: undefined
        },
        max: 300,
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          pointStart: 2010,
          pointInterval: 2
        }
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Energy Time-Shifting & Operating Reserves (No Firm Capacity From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.63942870272505, 5.22970733499782, 5.27920675745647, 5.30783211587234, 6.19751680650459, 7.3082097366251, 6.98022982001149, 7.13503050555605, 7.61987581404283, 7.60347325311543, 9.61344293269395, 13.3757198039836, 13.3384931273145, 22.0784478667247, 28.3335699220639, 40.7908062298414, ]
      }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Energy Time-Shifting (No Operating Reserves From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.54572501067027, 5.14824089370969, 5.29820021228112, 6.63781456129245, 8.85688437771603, 13.8658896319254, 27.1931002936285, 39.9357130097189, 58.6214614824223, 77.1254106761073, 95.268406121634, 112.405884767091, 133.027723197789, 155.277682659625, 176.596178226657, 192.675764588631, ]
      }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Operating Reserves (No Energy Time-Shifting From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.21829103663336, 4.81291957130873, 5.02399582218993, 6.57908016456348, 7.63005997606452, 11.0257789859977, 13.330738818622, 19.4783948566959, 27.6707413376832, 36.5813442540389, 47.469590556968, 63.1212738306735, 84.0763878821262, 102.32992781037, 120.887859787506, 136.565976817233, ]
      }]

    });
  </script>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  Highcharts.chart('container4', {

    title: {
      text: 'High Battery Cost Case',
      style: {
        fontSize: "16px"
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      step: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: undefined
      },
      max: 300,
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      enabled: false
    },

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: 2010,
        pointInterval: 2
      }
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Energy Time-Shifting & Operating Reserves (No Firm Capacity From Storage)',
      data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.57743715547351, 5.16759082894289, 5.16241825223985, 5.14439305708559, 5.05030457659485, 5.07416720920075, 4.74613468727552, 4.86135888180044, 4.57243700972263, 3.21005303174178, 4.19807863644804, 5.19626628040456, 5.4910646217716, 7.97589112588165, 10.2510871811584, 17.3461595503648, ]
    }, {
      name: 'Firm Capacity & Energy Time-Shifting (No Operating Reserves From Storage)',
      data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.50105411682933, 5.0913241792388, 5.15834598573316, 5.28947748602645, 5.6428616301249, 6.69345386943927, 8.41024825375956, 10.7921797139738, 14.1403806758731, 22.226765757974, 33.1613582581713, 45.8937441121399, 64.2670833917625, 83.84755649335, 97.6334741298098, 108.616739058021, ]
    }, {
      name: 'Firm Capacity & Operating Reserves (No Energy Time-Shifting From Storage)',
      data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.21625879407406, 4.80766191119213, 4.94252488836913, 5.82876338692197, 6.25057839402891, 7.10524981051512, 8.25532328086167, 10.5225270531993, 11.6653350971262, 15.5267974765324, 20.5477797210612, 25.8764046693577, 34.7879150374453, 46.5393009966628, 52.3945287374012, 65.0583419652337, ]
    }]

  });
</script>


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    title: {
        text: 'Low Battery Cost Case',
        style: {          
            fontSize: '16px'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Capacity (GW)'
        },
        max: 300    
    },
    labels: {
            step: 0
        },
    legend: {
      
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
         margin: 30,
         enabled: false
    },
      credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 2010,
            pointInterval: 2
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Energy Time-Shifting & Operating Reserves (No Firm Capacity From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 4.21110359791565, 6.84334322867839, 7.20182619975514, 7.8004278261306, 10.1063979510877, 13.7963553953421, 14.6735914371287, 18.5837874315195, 20.3731482407672, 24.0988019699228, 32.0357544751444, 45.1519218212058, 56.3857942558924, 81.1292491322195, 95.7124408905994, 131.978838410468,]
    }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Energy Time-Shifting (No Operating Reserves From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 3.70492103862706, 6.32644821179908, 6.7912945899555, 10.8852803548114, 17.2185962209215, 31.6655455463024, 53.0346762234928, 79.5213653476683, 99.0449876736713, 122.329600848415, 149.816960931063, 184.311271042092, 218.757764806966, 254.683442071981, 290.19930101708, 346.882919482988,]
    }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Operating Reserves (No Energy Time-Shifting From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.5286257976622, 5.12758943424106, 5.99409380798642, 9.76453882541978, 12.0745968401012, 21.1834214272343, 33.1674795094693, 48.7307134642147, 56.9008609975166, 68.4659981520015, 84.0579790344369, 101.373936044519, 120.070540082055, 142.483062401683, 160.447936224237, 185.693139471677,]
    }]

});
        </script>
                     
<script type="text/javascript">

Highcharts.chart('container3', {

    title: {
        text: 'Reference Cost Case',
        style: {
         fontSize: "16px"
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: undefined
        },
        max:300,
         labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        enabled:false
    },
      credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 2010,
            pointInterval: 2
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Energy Time-Shifting & Operating Reserves (No Firm Capacity From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.63942870272505, 5.22970733499782, 5.27920675745647, 5.30783211587234, 6.19751680650459, 7.3082097366251, 6.98022982001149, 7.13503050555605, 7.61987581404283, 7.60347325311543, 9.61344293269395, 13.3757198039836, 13.3384931273145, 22.0784478667247, 28.3335699220639, 40.7908062298414,]
    }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Energy Time-Shifting (No Operating Reserves From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.54572501067027, 5.14824089370969, 5.29820021228112, 6.63781456129245, 8.85688437771603, 13.8658896319254, 27.1931002936285, 39.9357130097189, 58.6214614824223, 77.1254106761073, 95.268406121634, 112.405884767091, 133.027723197789, 155.277682659625, 176.596178226657, 192.675764588631,]
    }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Operating Reserves (No Energy Time-Shifting From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.21829103663336, 4.81291957130873, 5.02399582218993, 6.57908016456348, 7.63005997606452, 11.0257789859977, 13.330738818622, 19.4783948566959, 27.6707413376832, 36.5813442540389, 47.469590556968, 63.1212738306735, 84.0763878821262, 102.32992781037, 120.887859787506, 136.565976817233,]
    }]

});
        </script></div>
                  
                  
<script type="text/javascript">

Highcharts.chart('container4', {

    title: {
        text: 'High Battery Cost Case',
        style: {
         fontSize: "16px"
        }
    },
xAxis: {
        step: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: undefined
        },
        max:300,
         labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        enabled:false
    },
    
      credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 2010,
            pointInterval: 2
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Energy Time-Shifting & Operating Reserves (No Firm Capacity From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.57743715547351, 5.16759082894289, 5.16241825223985, 5.14439305708559, 5.05030457659485, 5.07416720920075, 4.74613468727552, 4.86135888180044, 4.57243700972263, 3.21005303174178, 4.19807863644804, 5.19626628040456, 5.4910646217716, 7.97589112588165, 10.2510871811584, 17.3461595503648,]
    }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Energy Time-Shifting (No Operating Reserves From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.50105411682933, 5.0913241792388, 5.15834598573316, 5.28947748602645, 5.6428616301249, 6.69345386943927, 8.41024825375956, 10.7921797139738, 14.1403806758731, 22.226765757974, 33.1613582581713, 45.8937441121399, 64.2670833917625, 83.84755649335, 97.6334741298098, 108.616739058021,]
    }, {
        name: 'Firm Capacity & Operating Reserves (No Energy Time-Shifting From Storage)',
        data: [0.038, 0.1532, 0.2706, 0.8332, 1.3213, 2.21625879407406, 4.80766191119213, 4.94252488836913, 5.82876338692197, 6.25057839402891, 7.10524981051512, 8.25532328086167, 10.5225270531993, 11.6653350971262, 15.5267974765324, 20.5477797210612, 25.8764046693577, 34.7879150374453, 46.5393009966628, 52.3945287374012, 65.0583419652337,]
    }]

});
        </script>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think it's something related to `Bootstrap styles` - if you comment the stylesheet link in your jsfiddle, you'll see all three charts has the same xAxis text; you can check this also by commenting the `<div class="col-md-9">` or changing the class of `<div class="col-md-6">` of the "container2" div to `<div class="col-md-6">`. See [forked/modified example](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/59srtLbw/).

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. The first column doesn't have as much room as the other two.  I was hoping HighCharts had a way to override the labels regardless.

Comment: consider then post an entry in highcharts official support forum - maybe they can consider it for a future release or give you more help. Good luck, sfjeld.